# Different equation is given for "position"

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, time, velocity, displacement

$$s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$$
Assuming, $u=0$

$$s=\frac{1}{2}at^2$$
$$a=\frac{2s}{t^2}$$

So I got a function for acceleration.

$$v=u+at$$
$$v=\frac{2s}{t} \tag{1}$$

In reality I know that $s=vt$ when velocity is constant. Here the tag 1 equation don't have anything to do with acceleration according to that equation. I believe both term will give different solution. So there's something wrong happening with these equation,isn't it? (Side-note : I know calculus but I was defining them in general term)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationships $s = s_{initial} + ut + {1 \over 2} a t^2$ and $v = u + at$ assume constant acceleration. (You left out the initial position $s_{initial}$ in your relationship.)    Your results $a = {2s \over t^2}$ and $v = {2s \over t}$ are correct, assuming the initial position $s_{initial}$ and initial velocity $u$ are both zero.

$a$ is constant. But $v$ is not constant (unless $a$ is zero) since given acceleration the velocity  $v(t) = at$ where $a$ is constant but t changes. So $s \ne vt$; $s = \int_{o}^{t} v(t) \enspace dt =\int_{o}^{t} at \enspace dt$, and with $a$ constant $s = {a t^2 \over 2}$.

If $a$ is zero, $v = u$, a constant, and $s = s_{initial} + ut$. If the initial position $s_{initial}$ is zero, $s = ut$ where $u$ is the constant initial velocity; that is $s = \int_{o}^{t} u \enspace dt$ where $u$ is constant.

Answer (score 1):

Your expression is correct, as you can check by, e.g., [plotting the expressions](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hx6obpkthm).

You explicitly assumed the initial velocity to be zero. If the velocity is constant, then the final formula will give the correct expression: the particle doesn't move and the position is constant.

Comment: But why not the first one?

Comment: @Unknown all the expressions agree when $u = 0$ (which is the assumption you made)

Comment: Assume an object is moving with velocity 10 m/s. So it will travel 10 meter in a sec. That's what we exactly know, but while using first expression I will get $v=\dfrac{2s}{t}$ $s=\dfrac{vt}{2}$ that the object will move 5 meter in a sec..

Comment: @Unknown $v = \frac{2s}{t}$ was derived assuming the initial velocity to be $0$. In your problem, you assumed the initial velocity to be $10$ meters per second. That's why the predictions do not agree. If you stick to $u=0$, $v = \frac{2s}{t}$ is perfectly correct, regardless of the acceleration

Comment: While the expression does not depend on the acceleration, you did assume implicitly an initial condition for the velocity

Comment: The acceleration is constant based on the relationships used.  The velocity is not constant since it is acceleration times time.  See my response

Answer (score 1):

If $v$ is constant then $a=0$. Further if you assume the initial velocity $u=0$, then $v=0$ (since there is no acceleration) and indeed $s=0$ since there is no displacement at a constant velocity of $0$.  Thus the equations $v=2s/t$ and $v=s/t$ are perfectly consistent since $s=0$ on the right of each, and $v=0$ on the left of each.